# zsh : illegal hardware instruction python run.py

Tags: python, conda

I'm using M2 MacBook Air and using Conda environment. I installed python3.6 by configuring channel. So in my Conda env when I check python --version result is Python 3.6.13
The reason why I use python 3.6 is because of college lecture. Many good people advised me at latest question that don't use python 3.6 but professor told us only use python 3.6
This is my code in run.py

```
from imageatm.components import DataPrep
dp = DataPrep(
    image_dir='~~~',
    samples_file='data.json',
    job_dir= './sample'
)
dp.run(resize=True)

from imageatm.components import Training
trainer = Training(dp.image_dir, dp.job_dir,
epochs_train_dense=3, epochs_train_all=1)
trainer.run()

from imageatm.components import Evaluation
e = Evaluation(image_dir=dp.image_dir, job_dir=dp.job_dir)
e.run()
```

I already installed imageatm in my Conda env.
Why this error code 'zsh : illegal hardware instruction python run.py' happen?

I tried to configuring channel but it doesn't work..
I think its hardware problem..

This is my Conda list

```
absl-py                   0.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ansiwrap                  0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
async_generator           1.10             py36h28b3542_0  
attrs                     22.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
awscli                    1.24.10                  pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
botocore                  1.26.10                  pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2023.01.10           hecd8cb5_0  
cached-property           1.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
cachetools                4.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2022.12.7                pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        2.0.12                   pypi_0    pypi
clang                     5.0                      pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
dataclasses               0.8                      pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 4.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
docutils                  0.16                     pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.4                      pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.35.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.48.2                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.4                      pypi_0    pypi
imageatm                  0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
imageio                   2.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        4.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-resources       5.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
jinja2                    3.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
jmespath                  0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            7.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
jupyter_core              4.8.1            py36hecd8cb5_0  
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0  
keras                     2.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-vis                 0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
libcxx                    14.0.6               h9765a3e_0  
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h1de35cc_0  
markdown                  3.3.7                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.0.1            py36h9ed2024_0  
matplotlib                3.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4            py36h1de35cc_0  
mock                      5.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
multidict                 5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.5.9                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 6.0.7                    py36_0  
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
ncurses                   6.4                  hcec6c5f_0  
nest-asyncio              1.5.6                    pypi_0    pypi
networkx                  2.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.19.5                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1t               hca72f7f_0  
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pandoc                    2.12                 hecd8cb5_3  
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
papermill                 2.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    8.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       21.2.2           py36hecd8cb5_0  
protobuf                  3.19.6                   pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pyparsing                 3.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.13               h88f2d9e_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pywavelets                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    5.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     25.0.2                   pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  hca72f7f_0  
requests                  2.27.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
s3transfer                0.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-image              0.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.24.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                59.6.0                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.41.1               h6c40b1e_0  
tenacity                  8.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               1.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                1.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
textwrap3                 0.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tifffile                  2020.9.3                 pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h5d9f67b_0  
tornado                   6.1              py36h9ed2024_0  
tqdm                      4.64.1                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 4.3.3            py36hecd8cb5_0  
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                  pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.15                  pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_1  
werkzeug                  2.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1                   pypi_0    pypi
wrapt                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.10               h6c40b1e_1  
yarl                      1.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
zeromq                    4.3.4                h23ab428_0  
zipp                      3.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.13               h4dc903c_0
```

Comment: That means either the python interpreter or the library you're using has a bug, it shouldn't be a problem with your code.

Comment: Thx very much! Is above information insufficient for clarifying what makes problem? If there are more information that I need to describe, could you tell me some?

Comment: You should report it to the imageatm library maintainers.

Comment: We need to see the rest of the Conda environment (`conda list`). Very likely one or more of your packages is compiled with hardware optimizations that are not compatible with emulating via Rosetta. For example, the MKL implementation of BLAS/LAPACK will install but can't run on Apple Silicon even with emulation.

Comment: @merv Can you advise which version of imageatm need to run my code?

Comment: [Edit] the dependency list into the question; you shouldn't be asking a new question if it's about the same problem and there aren't any answers that adding the information would invalidate.

Comment: That said, one way you can get this with Python 3.6 on an M1 Mac is if you're using Intel instructions that Rosetta 2 can't translate. If that's the problem, it won't be fixed without either using a version of Python that's natively available compiled for M1, _or_ using a real Intel CPU instead of Apple's emulation.

Comment: @Jiminji, if your professor is telling you only to use Python 3.6, your university should be giving you access to a computer lab or other resources where Python 3.6 and the other necessary dependencies will run correctly, so you can run on a system your university's IT will support instead of on your own.

Comment: (in general, numeric computing is the primary place where Intel's optional vectorization instructions come in really useful, but they're not used so much by general-purpose software -- particularly given the compatibility hit that would come with running only on a subset of Intel CPUs that support whichever particular extension set is in use -- hence Rosetta not bothering to implement them).

Comment: I can't help any further with this: 80% of the packages are from PyPI, and who knows what static libraries they have linked in their .whl. I doubt that any of the Conda packages are the problem (e.g., does starting Python work on it's own?).