# zsh : illegal hardware instruction python run.py 2nd question

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

[zsh : illegal hardware instruction python run.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76008295/zsh-illegal-hardware-instruction-python-run-py?noredirect=1#comment134058050_76008295)

This is my latest question.

```
absl-py                   0.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ansiwrap                  0.8.4                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
async_generator           1.10             py36h28b3542_0  
attrs                     22.2.0                   pypi_0    pypi
awscli                    1.24.10                  pypi_0    pypi
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
botocore                  1.26.10                  pypi_0    pypi
ca-certificates           2023.01.10           hecd8cb5_0  
cached-property           1.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
cachetools                4.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2022.12.7                pypi_0    pypi
charset-normalizer        2.0.12                   pypi_0    pypi
clang                     5.0                      pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
colorama                  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
dataclasses               0.8                      pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 4.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
docutils                  0.16                     pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.4                      pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.35.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.48.2                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
idna                      3.4                      pypi_0    pypi
imageatm                  0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
imageio                   2.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        4.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-resources       5.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
jinja2                    3.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
jmespath                  0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
joblib                    1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter_client            7.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
jupyter_core              4.8.1            py36hecd8cb5_0  
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0  
keras                     2.2.4                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-vis                 0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
libcxx                    14.0.6               h9765a3e_0  
libffi                    3.3                  hb1e8313_2  
libsodium                 1.0.18               h1de35cc_0  
markdown                  3.3.7                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.0.1            py36h9ed2024_0  
matplotlib                3.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   0.8.4            py36h1de35cc_0  
mock                      5.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
multidict                 5.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbclient                  0.5.9                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 6.0.7                    py36_0  
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
ncurses                   6.4                  hcec6c5f_0  
nest-asyncio              1.5.6                    pypi_0    pypi
networkx                  2.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.19.5                   pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1t               hca72f7f_0  
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pandoc                    2.12                 hecd8cb5_3  
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
papermill                 2.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    8.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       21.2.2           py36hecd8cb5_0  
protobuf                  3.19.6                   pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pyparsing                 3.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.13               h88f2d9e_0  
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pywavelets                1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyyaml                    5.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     25.0.2                   pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.2                  hca72f7f_0  
requests                  2.27.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
s3transfer                0.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-image              0.17.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.24.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                59.6.0                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.41.1               h6c40b1e_0  
tenacity                  8.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               1.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                1.13.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      1.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
textwrap3                 0.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tifffile                  2020.9.3                 pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.12               h5d9f67b_0  
tornado                   6.1              py36h9ed2024_0  
tqdm                      4.64.1                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 4.3.3            py36hecd8cb5_0  
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                  pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.15                  pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_1  
werkzeug                  2.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1                   pypi_0    pypi
wrapt                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.10               h6c40b1e_1  
yarl                      1.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
zeromq                    4.3.4                h23ab428_0  
zipp                      3.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.13               h4dc903c_0
```

This is my Conda list. What should I do to run my code??

Comment: The error needs to be **included in the question itself, as text**. Images and links don't count towards [mre] guidelines for the reasons given in [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: You should provide this information as an edit to your previous question, not as a separate question.

Comment: Ok sorry guys...